# How can I setup yearly subscription using in-app Billing in Android?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

How can I setup yearly subscription using in-App Billing in Android app?

Most software are sold in subscription model these days. As business software are going to the cloud people are paying for software on annual subscription. There should be an easy way to provide subscription model in mobile phone app.

Comment: Looks like some friends do not like my question. Do your math? If you sell your app for 99 cents, how do you take care of your costs(time) unless you would publish super hit apps every quarter or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Goolge have added support for in app billing.](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_subscriptions.html)
should be simple if you already have in app billing implemented

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here.
https://market.android.com/support/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=140504

Currently, Android Market doesn't support subscription billing. Please note that collecting payments through your application is not allowed under the Android Market Developer Distribution Agreement.